# What are the characteristics of "Miniland" scale?

Tags: terminology

I have heard many references to "Miniland" scale. From what I have seen, this style of building mostly includes figurines that are larger than normal mini-figs.

What are some other characteristics of "Miniland" scale?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Mini style {used in LEGO sets and by collectors, not Miniland}

Mini scale/style is typically much smaller than normal LEGO. In Mini scale/style, figures are formed with 2-3 blocks.

Mini scale/style {if I remember correctly} didn't gain popularity until recently. It's so far been popularly used in the LEGO Architecture sets, and in a few others of common landmarks.

It's also common to see three-to-five-dollar packages that contain buildable models {sold in the LEGO stores} in the Mini scale/style.

Examples of Mini sets include:

- [4837 Mini Trains](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/4837-1)
- [5761 Mini Digger](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/5761)
- [5864 Mini Helicopter](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/5864)

### Miniland style {used by Legoland amusement parks and a few LEGO sets}

I believe that the LEGO amusement parks use something close to miniland scale. It is, however, much different than normal Mini style/scale. One notable fact is that the people have larger heads. I know this is true for the one in Billund, but I'm not sure about the one in California.

[Here](http://www.legoland.dk/da/Oplev-LEGOLAND/) and [here](http://california.legoland.com/Explore/Rides_and_attractions/miniland_usa/) are the pages of Minilands Billund and California, respectively. The Billund miniland doesn't have its' own page, but it's on the interactive map at the link provided.

A Miniland Flickr group is [here](http://www.flickr.com/groups/975302@N21/) if you want to see what Miniland style/scale is.

EDIT! As Zhaph-Ben Duguid pointed out, the Legoland amusement parks are called Miniland, but do not use the Mini scale/style. They use a strange hybrid between DUPLO and LEGO Mini scale/style. It is actually not the more common Mini style/scale used in sets. I've updated this answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'd suggest that Miniland is **larger** than standard LEGO - the figure's heads in the Minilands at the parks are made of a number of bricks alone - and are larger than minifig heads.

Comment: The Lego parks had the term Miniland first; can you cite its use outside the parks?

Comment: I too would like a citation for LEGO Architecture being "miniland" - I considered it micro-scale.

Comment: Sorry, but your edit forces me to -1. As far as I know miniland scale is what is at the parks, and your first paragraph is about micro-scale. This answer is just getting wronger over time.

Comment: @Erik Olson and Joe Wreschnig: I've clarified that. You're right: The Architecture sets are not built in any form of Miniland. They're Mini style. not Miniland style.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: Nope. They're not called Micro at all, anywhere. They're called Mini. See here: http://search2.lego.com/exec/?q=micro&pt=&lang=2057&cc=US&u= and here: http://search2.lego.com/?pt=&cc=US&lang=2057&u=&q=mini&x=0&y=0

Comment: @Java: Can you please find a citation for that? Micro-building is a very common Lego term; Lego themselves most recently used it in an MBA set, there is a micro-scale Flikr group at http://www.flickr.com/groups/microscale/; there is a micro-scale category on MOC at http://www.mocpages.com/directory.php/51; etc.

Comment: By comparison, your "mini" link contains only three relevant results.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: WTF are you talking about? I searched the entire LEGO.com for Micro and found nada. I searched the entire LEGO.com for Mini and found **nine-hundred-fifty-seven** results. Where'd you get "three relevant results" from? P.S. My official term w/957 results vs your 2 links: I believe the official term wins.

Comment: thanks for making it a bit clearer, i had also heard of micro-scale but knew that it was separate from this style of building. I know about the more official "mini" style too now.

Comment: Ah, the joys of search results. There's a tab on the second of @JavaAndCSharp's links that contains 957 results, compared with the 4 models that were available in the GB shop - however most of those links do not talk explicitly about mini-models, but instead list the same 4 or 5 models. Poor indexing strategy really, they should be excluding the navigation from their crawls.

Comment: @Java: http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/20201_Microbuild_Designer Official set. Still waiting for the cite. Don't just read numbers, actually look at the results please.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: Yup. Looked at the results; they give 14 Lego sets in the 'mini' scale. As you pointed out, there is also a set {may be more than one} in the 'micro' scale. LEGO designers need to agree on one standard term. IMHO, these two scales are the same. Do you agree?